# No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [nz.cri.gns.mapservice.userdomain.DataUser]

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink

I have two data sources. The moment I add ANY repository to the second datasource, this error comes up for whatever entity the repository used.

Using spring config instead of persistance, and EclipseLink JPA. The strange thing is that is has nearly identical to a working project that was used as template. Different data sources and obviously different tree scanned, but otherwise the config seems setup exactly the same. What is the equivalent spring data config equivalent to exclude-unlisted-classes. I will happily put up code but can anyone give me hint of where I should start looking?

stackdump looks like:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [nz.cri.gns.mapservice.userdomain.DataUser] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Managed] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific nz.cri.gns.mapservice.userdomain.DataUser property or a global false element.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entityEmbeddableManagedTypeNotFound(MetamodelImpl.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:519)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)

Answer (score 1):

Duh! Make sure everything in the SetPackagesToScan is spelled correctly! No errors result from a typo, but classes dont go into the metamodel either.

Comment: I had the same error and found that I changed the package (from com.aaa.jpa.repository to com.bbb.jpa.repository) but forgot to update EclispeLink setPackagesToScan. Once I updat setPackagesToScan, the error is gone.